# Create folders with FTP

Tags: raspbian, file-sharing

I am using the RPi as an FTP Server using vsftpd and trying to save logs and images from a Windows PC using the program Cognex Insight Explorer, when using a path in Windows I can save the file anywhere I want inside the FTP folder, but in the RPi I can only save files in the FTP root folder.

This works with Windows FTP:

```
C:\FTP\Data\TestLog
```

Tried this in RPi:

```
/home/pi/FTP/Data/TestLog
/Data/TestLog
```

I have created the folders from the path I want to save the files but I can only write to root.

Comment: What happens if you try to write to a folder below the root?  What, if anything, do the log files say?

Comment: Writing inside a folder just doesn't create anything, I think the way Cognex program commands work ir that it tries to write a file with the dash ("/") as part of the name of the file and with Windows it's Ok to try that because it is recognized as a folder path, but in Linux it may just give an error that the name is incorrect.